# Easiest way to decode basic authorization in .NET

Tags: vb.net, authorization, httplistener

I need to validate a basic authorization header that is being sent to my HttpListener in VB.NET.  I'm grabbing the header like so (feel free to point out better ways to do this as well):

```
EncodedAuth = Context.Request.Headers.GetValues("Authorization")(1)
```

Now how do I decode them?  I understand [the theory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_access_authentication) but I can't seem to find the right code.

Thank you.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This should do it...

```
basicData = System.Text.ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetString( System.Convert.FromBase64String( EncodedAuth ) )
```

This will give you a string in the format "username:password".  Split the string on ":" and you'll get the credentials.